# How to extract specified path from Windows PATH using bash

Tags: windows, bash

In Git bash under Windows when I run `echo $PATH` command, I'm getting the following output:

```
c/Windows/System32:/c/Python27:/c/Python27/Scripts:c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub:/c/Program Files (x86)/Private Shell:/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSH/bin:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/:/c/Program Files/Boot2Docker for Windows:c/Windows/System32:/c/Python27:/c/Python27/Scripts
```

What I need to do is extracting whole POSIX path, like `/c/Program Files/Boot2Docker for Windows` to variable in bash script, identifying it by `Boot2Docker for Windows` phrase.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $PATH | grep -o "[^:]*Boot2Docker for Windows[^:]*"
```

returns:

```
/c/Program Files/Boot2Docker for Windows
```

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH regex:

```
[[ $PATH =~ ([^:]*"Boot2Docker for Windows"[^:]*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
/c/Program Files/Boot2Docker for Windows
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `read` with a custom `IFS`.

```
b2ddir=
IFS=: read -a a <<<"$WPATH"
for p in "${a[@]}"; do
    case "$p" in
        *"Boot2Docker for Windows"*)
        b2ddir=$p
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
declare -p b2ddir
```